# Arrumar função buscar em lista circular duplamente encadeada

Tags: c

Galera tem como arrumar minha função buscar ou dar a ideia do erro ? tenho que buscar o nome da pessoa que esta inserida na lista e a função remover esta com um bug

vlw 
abraço.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MAX_NOME 50

typedef struct pes
{
    char nome[MAX_NOME];
    int num;
} pessoa;

typedef struct cel
{
    pessoa *conteudo;
    struct cel *seg;
    struct cel *ant;
} celula;

pessoa *CriaPessoa(char *nome, int num)
{
    pessoa *nova = (pessoa*) malloc(sizeof(pessoa));
    strcpy(nova->nome, nome);
    nova->num = num;

    return nova;
}


void Inserir(celula* p, pessoa *x)
{

    celula* elemento = (celula*) malloc (sizeof(celula));
    elemento->conteudo = x;

        elemento->seg = p->seg;
        elemento->ant = p;
        if(p->seg == p)
            p->ant = elemento;
        if(p->seg)
            p->seg->ant = elemento;
        p->seg = elemento;
        printf("inseriu %s\n", p->seg->conteudo->nome);
}

pessoa * Remover(celula* p)
{
    pessoa *aux = NULL;
    celula *rem = p;
    aux = p->conteudo;

    if(p->seg)
        p->seg->ant = p->ant;
    p->ant->seg = p->seg;

    free(rem);
    return aux;
}

celula * Buscar(celula *lista, char nome[])
{
    for(;lista->seg!=NULL;lista = lista->seg);
        if(lista->seg->conteudo->nome == nome)
                return nome;

    return NULL;


    }


void Imprime(celula *lista)
{
    printf("\n\n");
    celula *aux = lista;

    for( ;lista->seg!=aux; lista = lista->seg){/* lista->seg*/
            if(lista->seg->conteudo->nome)
                printf("nome: %s -- numero: %d\n", lista->seg->conteudo->nome, lista->seg->conteudo->num);
            else
                printf("Cabeca\n");
                system("pause");
        }
}



int main()
{
    celula *lista = (celula*) malloc( sizeof(celula));
    lista->seg = lista->ant = lista;

    Inserir(lista ,CriaPessoa("eduardo",10));
    Inserir(lista ,CriaPessoa("andrei",12));
    Inserir(lista ,CriaPessoa("luiz",13));
    Inserir(lista ,CriaPessoa("caio",14));
    Inserir(lista ,CriaPessoa("daniel",15));
    Inserir(lista ,CriaPessoa("joao",16));
    Inserir(lista ,CriaPessoa("pedro",17));

    Imprime(lista);
    celula *x = Buscar(lista, "pedro");
    printf("Achou %s na lista\n", x->conteudo->nome);
    /*Remover(x);*/

    Imprime(lista);
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Que bug??? Erro de compilação, execução... (à primeira vista noto que o tipo de retorno de `Buscar` é `celula*` mas você está tentando retornar um `char[]`; será que você não queria retornar `lista` em vez de `nome`?)

Comment: não busca nada mais não da erro no codigo e no meu codigo não da Warning  nem nada, bem estranho!

Comment: @matheus Francisco já compilou com `-Wall` para ver realmente se não tem warnings?

Comment: Numa segunda leitura, vejo que também está comparando strings com  `==`. A menos que se esteja comparando por identidade, i.e. se é a *mesma string*, e não meramente duas strings iguais, isso sempre vai dar falso (daí a busca nunca retornar nada, sempre nulo). Sugiro usar [`strcmp`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) (na prática) ou então comparar os caracteres das strings um a um (para aprendizado). Mas conserte o problema do tipo de retorno primeiro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como disse @mgibsonbr, na função de busca o tipo do retorno e a verificação do nome estavam errados.

```
celula *Busca(celula *lista, char nome[])
{
        celula *achado = NULL;
        celula *aux = lista;
        while(lista->seg != aux)
        {
                if(strcmp(lista->elemento->nome, nome) == 0)
                        achado = lista;
                lista = lista->seg;
        }
        return achado;
}
```

Para a remoção é importante verificar se o elemento a ser removido é o primeiro e atualizar o valor da lista na função principal.

```
celula *Remover(celula *lista, celula *p)
{
    celula *rem = p;

    if(lista == p)
        lista = p->seg;

    p->seg->ant = p->ant;
    p->ant->seg = p->seg;

    free(rem);
    return lista;
}
```

Função principal.

```
celula *x = Buscar(lista, "pedro");
printf("Achou %s na lista\n", x->conteudo->nome);
lista = Remover(lista, x);
```

OBS: A função de remoção estará certa se a função de inserção está seguindo o conceito de lista circular duplamente encadeada corretamente.

Comment: Obrigado cara ajudou muito!

Comment: estou tentando fazer uma funcao para inverter a lista mas esta dando um warring na  primeira linha do if desta funcao falando q esta com erro no pontiero mais não consigo ver qual ponteiro                         void inverter(celula**lst){
 if((*lst)->seg == lst){
  printf("cabeça ");
 }else{
  celula*p;
        celula*q;
        celula*x;
  p = q = x = (*lst)->seg;
     while( x != lst ){
         p = p->seg;
         x->seg = q;
         q = x;
         x = p;
     }
     (*lst)->seg->seg = lst;
     (*lst)->seg = q;
 }
}

Comment: Se trata se uma lista circular duplamente encadeada, círculos não tem começo nem fim. A partir do cabeça da lista percorra-a usando o ponteiro `ant` que terá sua lista "invertida".